# Amazon sp-api ConfirmShipment does not set "Delivery Service"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am using Amazon sp-api and confirming the Tracking Number like below:

```
public bool UpdateTrackingNumber(DtoShipment dto)
{
    ConfirmShipmentOrderItemsList orderItems = new ConfirmShipmentOrderItemsList();
    foreach (OrderItem item in dto.LstOrderItem)
    {
        orderItems.Add(new ConfirmShipmentOrderItem(item.OrderItemId, item.Quantity));
    }
    ConfirmShipmentRequest confirmShipmentRequest = new ConfirmShipmentRequest()
    {
        MarketplaceId = getMarketPlaceId(dto.CountryCode),
        PackageDetail = new PackageDetail()
        {
            TrackingNumber = dto.TrackingNumber,
            CarrierName = dto.CarrierName,  // "DPD Home 0-31.5kg"
            CarrierCode = dto.CarrierCode,  // "DPD"
            PackageReferenceId = "1",
            ShipDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
            OrderItems = orderItems
        }
    };
    AmazonConnection _connAmazon = createAmazonConnection("marketplaceId");
    return _connAmazon.Orders.ConfirmShipment(dto.AmazonOrderId, confirmShipmentRequest);
}
```

It sets the Tracking Number successfully, but the "Delivery Service" field stays empty. I am not sure that was a problem or not, but I am wondering if it is possible to set that value also with this method?

**Edit**:
*When I set the tracking number by using Amazon interface, "DPD" is automatically selected for "Carrier" and "Other" is automatically selected for "Delivery Service" and "DPD Home 0-31.5kg" is under that.*

**Edit 2:**
*When I set via API, Tracking Number and Carrier have been set, but "Delivery Service" is not."*
[image]

*If I use Amazon interface, Amazon brings me all fields filled like that. I only write the "Tracking Number" and confirm shipment.*
[image]

**Edit 3:**
Thanks @Charlieface, It worked like that:

```
            PackageDetail = new PackageDetail()
            {
                TrackingNumber = dto.TrackingNumber,
                CarrierName = "",
                CarrierCode = dto.CarrierCode,  // "DPD"
                PackageReferenceId = "1",
                ShipDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                OrderItems = orderItems,
                ShippingMethod = dto.CarrierName  // "DPD Home 0-31.5kg"
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which SDK are you using, I wasn't aware there is one for C# other than the OpenAPI spec sheet. There is a specific list of carrier codes you need to use, see https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_1_9/amzn-base._TTH_.xsd so if it doesn't match it won't accept it (for custom carriers you need to use `Other` and specify `CarrierName`, for specified carriers you only use `CarrierCode`).

Comment: I am using a nuget package named "CSharpAmazonSpAPI". And I think it uses AWSSDK.Core (>= 3.7.302.12 && < 4.0.0) My CarrierName "DPD" is in the list. So there is no problem on setting Carriage value. I can see it as "Carrier" after API call. Only "Delivery Service" is not updated.

Comment: I think that goes in `shippingMethod`. But your SDK is old if it's still using AWSSDK, you don't need AWS anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend @Charlieface. I send `CarrierName` empty and `ShippingMethod` as **"DPD Home 0-31.5kg"** and it worked. If you post this in a new message, I can also accept it as an answer. But please elaborate "if it's still using AWSSDK, you don't need AWS anymore". What do you mean, I could not understand.

Comment: SP-API historically needed an AWS token and an IAM user/role in order to function. It doesn't anymore, so if the package is still linking it then it's out of date. I suggest you create your own SDK off the OpenAPI/Swagger model, using NSwag or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-reference#packagedetail) indicates a `shippingMethod` property.

> | Name | Description | Schema |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | **carrierCode** *required* | Identifies the carrier that will deliver the package. This field is required for all marketplaces, see reference. | string |
> | **carrierName** *optional* | Carrier Name that will deliver the package. Required when carrierCode is "Others" | string |
> | **shippingMethod** *optional* | Ship method to be used for shipping the order. | string |

Process of elimination leads to this property being the one used for the "Delivery Srevice", and that is what we have found works.